# How to store data from user in php using wampserver?

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I have a college assignment in which I have to design a website and I have to store details from the user. I did a google search and I have a found a script which works fine for my registration page So I copied that script for my index.php page and I have created a table contact in phpymadmin using wampserver and inserted 3 columns Username, Email, Message. But now when I'm trying to enter some details and clicking on submit button the page is getting refreshed and data is not getting stored in the database.

```html
<form role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                 
 <!-- Name -->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" name="name">
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- E-Mail -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Message Area -->
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Write you message here..." style="height:232px;"></textarea>
 </div>

 <!-- Subtmit Button -->
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send" value="register">
  Send message
 </button>

</form>
```

```
<?php

include("contact.php");//make connection here
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $Username=$_POST['name'];//here getting result from the post array after submitting the form.
    $Email=$_POST['email'];//same
    $Message=$_POST['message'];//same


    if($Username=='')
    {
        //javascript use for input checking
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the name')</script>";
exit();//this use if first is not work then other will not show
    }

    if($Email=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the email')</script>";
exit();
    }

    if($Message=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the message')</script>";
    exit();
    }
//here query check weather if user already registered so can't register again.
    $check_email_query="select * from contact WHERE Email='$Email'";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_email_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)
    {
echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email is already exist in our database, Please try another one!')</script>";
exit();
    }
//insert the user into the database.
    $insert_user="insert into contact (Username,Email,Message) VALUE ('$Username','$Email','$Message')";
    if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_user))
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Thank you for contacting us')</script>";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: change `insert into contact (Username,Email,Message) VALUE` to `insert into contact (Username,Email,Message) VALUES`

Comment: `VALUE` should be `VALUES` and you have borrowed a very poor example of PHP code to **plagiarize**

Comment: What is there in `contact.php` ? Database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add `name='register'` in `<button>`. Because, you are using `isset($_POST['register'])` And, there is no need of `value="register"`, as you have declared `Send Message` as value there in button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-send" name="register">
        Send message
</button>
```

2) Change `VALUE` to `VALUES` in this query.

```
$insert_user="insert into contact (Username,Email,Message) VALUES ('$Username','$Email','$Message')";
```